# Image scaling and positioning in ImageView inside AppWidget layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

**NOTE** problem solved... it was an issue in the bitmap itself and not the XML layout used to display it... see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619000/image-scaling-and-positioning-in-imageview-inside-appwidget-layout/56681236#comment99913579_56619000).  No need to read on unless you're curious!

---

When I set the content of an `ImageView` (N.B. inside an AppWidget layout) to a bitmap that is smaller than the physical pixel size of the `ImageView`, I'm sure that in the past (not sure how long ago) the bitmap would just get scaled up to fit... in my case the smaller image is exactly the same aspect ratio as the `ImageView` so this is exactly the effect I want.

But recently I noticed that this is no longer happening... the bitmap sits in the top left corner.  I've tried setting various attributes in the XML layout, but nothing has any effect.

E.g. I've tried:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"

android:scaleType="centerInside"

android:layout_gravity="center"
```

But still the image sits in the `ImageView` flush with the top left corner, with gaps to right and bottom.

XML (ImageView part):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_port"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

The `ImageView` sits within a parent defined in the XML as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:id="@+id/widget" >
```

Code to put image content URI in appwidget:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(imageViewId, uri);
appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

How it looks for image with size that matches the widget imageview:

[image]

How it looks for an image that is smaller than the widget imageview:

[image]

I want the smaller image to be scaled up to fit the ImageView (it's the same aspect ratio, so it will fit perfectly).

Comment: You can manually set scaled bitmap if it fits with your requirements

Comment: @Jasurbek I don't really want to be scaling bitmaps in the code.  Surely there must be a way of doing this via the XML?  Surely that's what `android:scaleType` is intended for?

Comment: Then check this link, hope you find it useful, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Comment: @Jasurbek those are just the same as the `scaleType` I said isn't having any effect in the XML

Comment: Can you attach an image for better understanding what you want?

Comment: And also how do you set the image in imageView? if programatically, attach your code here.

Comment: @kAvEh I provided more detail in the question

Comment: @drmrbrewer have you tried android:scaleType="fitXY" ?

Comment: @kAvEh yep, doesn't have any effect :-(

Comment: Please post the XML code containing the parent of this `ImageView`. Also, is it looking fine if you assign hard-coded height and width to your ` ImageView` along with `fitXY`( just to debug the issue) ?

Comment: have you tried to use something towards `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()`?

Comment: @Astha I added the XML for the parent of the `ImageView`.  @Victor I do implement such a method but my view is that when the bitmap is generated for the widget's imageview, which it does on a regular schedule, that bitmap should scale according the XML, even in the absence of any "options changed"... it should just happen.

Comment: already tried `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` with `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` being settle on `ImageView`?

Comment: I'm also not sure if your widget is resizable or if it's just a matter of scaling its content being rendered inside it. If widget's resizing is the case, you should consider using your `ImageView` being nested into a `GridView`. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Comment: @VictorR.Oliveira tried `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`... no effect.  The widget is resizable (the resizing handles in the OP screenshots resize the widget)... it's worked fine since forever.  The problem is with scaling the bitmap within the imageview bounds rather than with changing the widget (and imageview) bounds.  Thing is, in the past the bitmap DID used to scale up to fit the imageview bounds.  Something broke; not sure when... I wonder if it was when I migrated to using AndroidX libraries.

Comment: @drmrbrewer any chances of uploading a snapshot repo replicating this scenario so we could take a better look?

Comment: @VictorR.Oliveira thanks for suggesting this... in the process of creating a sample repo, I generated a bitmap for use in the sample project, and it was only then that I discovered that I was generating a smaller-than-imageview bitmap but writing to a bitmap having the full imageview dimensions, filling the gaps with transparency.  Hence the bitmap is actually the full size of the imageview (no scaling required), but the real content smaller than that.  Once I fixed that, the XML works without any changes... scaling the smaller bitmap to fit the imageview as it used to.  D'OH.

Comment: Always glad to help, even indirectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

OR

```
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```